# ColorTrackText in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to write this type of text ,is this possible?

[image]

Comment: This is a Spanned String . Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#multiple-styles).

Comment: @ADM not sure if that also works for coloring letters halfway.

Comment: No it will not . For that you are going to need something Else which i have no idea about . its gonna be tricky ..

Comment: Hi! Did my answer solve your question? If so, please accept it using the checkmark under the votes counter. Otherwise, let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Modifier.drawWithContent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).drawWithContent(kotlin.Function1)) and [`clipRect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/package-summary?hl=id#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).clipRect(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ClipOp,kotlin.Function1)) you can draw only part of the contents of the view. Then you need to put two identical `Text` in a `Box` and draw the desired part of each view:

```
@Composable
fun TwoColorText(
    text: String,
    color1: Color,
    color2: Color,
    part: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    val textView = @Composable { color: Color, leftMultiplier: Float, rightMultiplier: Float ->
        Text(
            text,
            color = color,
            fontSize = fontSize,
            fontStyle = fontStyle,
            fontWeight = fontWeight,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
            textDecoration = textDecoration,
            textAlign = textAlign,
            lineHeight = lineHeight,
            overflow = overflow,
            softWrap = softWrap,
            maxLines = maxLines,
            onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
            style = style,
            modifier = Modifier.drawWithContent {
                clipRect(
                    left = size.width * leftMultiplier,
                    right = size.width * rightMultiplier
                ) {
                    this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
                }
            }
        )
    }
    Box(modifier) {
        textView(color1, 0f, part)
        textView(color2, part, 1f)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Row(Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
    TwoColorText(
        "新鲜",
        color1 = Color.Black,
        color2 = Color.Red,
        part = 0.27f,
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp))
    TwoColorText(
        "消息",
        color1 = Color.Black,
        color2 = Color.Red,
        part = 0.27f,
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]